# Work around SQL array?

Tags: sql

I have a form that has 6 different inputs:

```
Form_No   VarChar2,
Form_Ver  Number, 
Org_No    VarChar2,
Item_No   VarChar2,
Form_Type VarChar2,
Line_No   Number
```

These inputs are then stored into a temp table. I need to build a function that takes the temp variables from the temp table to do some validation. I need to use an array to hold the variables.

I am pretty new to SQL. I have had some experience in it and other coding languages. I have realized that there is not an array in SQL. I was wondering if someone could help me get started or understand how they get around not using an array, and I will be able to finish it.

```
--Temp table that variables are put in

    INSERT INTO Temp Table
        VALUES
          (t_form_no,
           t_max_form_ver,
           t_org_no,
           t_item_no,
           t_form_type,
           t_line_no,

--Function
 Validation_Form
--need to have array here that takes in the temp variables from the temp table

--Then I have my validation scripts placed here
```

Comment: In what manner does a Table not satisfy your requirement for an Array?

Comment: What type of validation? Typically this should be done at the application layer, not database layer.

Comment: I dont actually get what exactly you want to do. I dont understand why do you need temp table, function and array all together.

Comment: Why do you have to use an array?  I also don't see how an array makes sense here as you have different data types and those 6 values should be together on a row and be related.  Why not have 7 columns in the temp table so that you can have an ID that is unique in case someone submits the same data multiple times that has to get cleaned up at some point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to get the same functionality as an array a temp table can work just fine. Here is how.

```
CREATE Table #Foo 
   (fooID INT NOT NULL Identity (1,1), 
    field1 varchar(20), 
    field2 varchar(20), 
    field3 varchar(20), 
    field4 varchar(20), 
    field5 varchar(20))
```

When you do the `INSERT INTO` this Table #Foo, the 1st row will be numeric and the additional fields will be whatever you insert into them.

Is this what you are trying to acheive?